# Enclose line of a text by html p tag

Tags: excel

On my Excel sheet, I have row text with line breaks.

```
This is a first line of text and is a sample text. 

This is a second line of text and is also a sample text.
```

I would like to convert enclose using excel functions(not VBA) in a column next to original.

```
<p>This is a first line of text and is a sample text. </p> 

<p>This is a second line of text and is also a sample text. </p>
```

I tried SUBSTITUTE function but in could not detect line start.

Comment: How did you try to detect it? Post the formula you used in your question. If the lines are in the same cell, there's usually a `line-feed` character.

Answer (score 0):

Your original text string contains `Line Break` (as mentioned by @RonRosenfeld) which you can google it online. Excel expression for it is `=CHAR(10)`.

So your original text string can be viewed as:

```
This is a first line of text and is a sample text. CHAR(10)
CHAR(10)
This is a second line of text and is also a sample text.
```

There are two line breaks so you could use the following nested **SUBSTITUTE** formula to replace the first and second line break separately to get the desired result:

```
="<p>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</p>"&CHAR(10),1),CHAR(10),CHAR(10)&"<p>",2)&"</p>"
```

Suppose you want to return the result in Cell `B1`, you need to make sure to click **Wrap Text** button under the `Home` tab so it will be displayed properly.

[image: Example]

**EDIT #2**

> As pointed out by @RonRosenfeld, the following formula should work for **multiple sentences** with line breaks:

```
="<p>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),"</p>"&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"<p>")&"</p>"
```

[image: Example 2]

My first answer has overlooked the fact that the two `CHAR(10)` line breaks are actually positioned consecutively so it would be a really simple process of replacing them both with the `<p></p>`.

Comment: Your idea is good but only seems to work for **two** lines of text, since you are replacing only the 1st and 2nd instances of `CHAR(10)`.  Suggest `="<p>" & SUBSTITUTE(G10, CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),"</p>" & CHAR(10)&CHAR(10) & "<p>") & "</p>"` which should handle any number of lines.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld that's it!! you are the master of **SUBSTITUTE** I must say. Thank you for sharing the knowledge :)